# Best way to import Vagrant box into amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vagrant, virtualbox

Right now, I have Vagrant box on Windows, VirtualBox Ubuntu. What is the best way for me to import into Amazon AWS. Also, Amazon AWS using a volume for each EC2 instance. How do I create that volume as well?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your box from a Vagrantfile? You might want to consider the vagrant-aws plugin to provision your instance.

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws

It allows you to configure block device mapping, and EBS storage if you need. It works like a charm.